# using react hook form on react native app

Tags: react-native, react-hook-form, react-ref, react-forms

I'm trying to create reusable Controller component that receives a `'name'` prop instead of copy-pasting the same Controller tags with different `'name'` prop again and again.

Instead of writing this:

MyScreen.tsx

```
       <Controller
          name="name"
          control={control}
          rules={{
            required: {value: true, message: 'Name is required'},
          }}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({onChange, value}: any) => (
            <Input
              error={errors.name}
              errorText={errors?.name?.message}
              onChangeText={(text: any) => onChange(text)}
              value={value}
              placeholder="Name"
            />
          )}
        />
       <Controller
          name="email"
          control={control}
          rules={{
            required: {value: true, message: 'Email is required'},
          }}
          defaultValue=""
          render={({onChange, value}: any) => (
            <Input
              error={errors.name}
              errorText={errors?.name?.message}
              onChangeText={(text: any) => onChange(text)}
              value={value}
              placeholder="Email"
            />
          )}
        />
```

I would like to have something like this:

MyScreen.tsx

```
<MyControllerComponet name ="name"/>
<MyControllerComponet name ="email"/>
```

And export the `MyControllerComponet` like this:

```
const MyControllerComponet= (props)=>{
const {handleSubmit, control, errors} = useForm();
 return (
    <View>
      <Controller
        name={props.name}
        control={control}
        rules={{
          required: {value: true, message: 'Email is required'},
          pattern: {
            value: EMAIL_REGEX,
            message: 'Not a valid email',
          },
        }}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({onChange, value}: any) => (
          <TextInput
            style={[styles.inputContainer, props.error, props.style]}
            {...props}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

This example doesn't work- the input/data doesn't pass from the Controller component to the `MyScreen` screen (from child to parent).
any ideas how can I make it work?

extra screenshots:

[MainScreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmbWE.png)

[MyControllerComponet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4ipz.png)

[final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caAAU.png)

as you can see, only 1,2 values (the first and second controllers in the MainScreen) logged to console when clicking onSubmit but the 3rd value doesn't.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in parent component

```js
const from = useForm({})
```

then you can extract other values from form like,

```
const {handleSubmit} = form;
```

You can pass form as a prop to `MyControllerComponet`.

```js
<MyControllerComponet name ="name" form={form} />
```

Then inside `MyControllerComponent`

```js
const { control, errors} =props.form;
```

Comment: i dont want to handleSubmit on MyControllerComponent, i want to have a button in parent component and when clicking submit invoke handleSubmit function.

Comment: Yes, My bad. I will remove that. in that case in parent component simply do `const {handleSubmit} = form;` or use directly as `form.handleSubmit`.

Comment: can you write it more organized please?
you mean in parent component do ```const {handleSubmit} = form``` instead of ```const {handleSubmit, control, errors, register, setValue, form} = useForm();``` ?

Comment: I meant you can keep the form instance in the parent component and pass it as a props to child `MyController` compnents. from there you can extract values like `control, errors` etc. and in parent component you can handle `handleSubmit`